# Scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing?

Tags: scala

Here is my code:

```
package example

object Lists {

  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if(xs.isEmpty){
        throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()
    }
    else {
        max(xs.tail)
    }
  }
}
```

When i run it in sbt console:

```
scala> import example.Lists._
scala> max(List(1,3,2))
```

I have the following error:

```
Scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Except to the fact that your code just throws a NoSuchElementException after recursively going through the list, there is nothing wrong with it. Is your sbt project structure correct?

Comment: This is for the coursera scala course right? `NotImplementedError` is what the original code does, so it must not be seeing your changes. Did you try reloading the REPL after making your changes?

Comment: In https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/programming/xIz9O/example-assignment

Comment: You need to be on sbt console not on scala repl

Comment: @theon how do you reload the repl?

Comment: @ultrajohn I think I meant `:q` followed by running `sbt console` again - but it's been 9 years since that comment, so memory is hazy :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

open example.Lists, you will see below lines:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = ???
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = ???
```

use `0` instead of `???`.

Comment: also, restart the Scala REPL

Answer (score 7):

Also, putting the correct recursive implementation for the max that should work

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if(xs.isEmpty){
      throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()
    }
    val tailMax =  if (xs.tail.isEmpty)  xs.head else max(xs.tail)
    if (xs.head >= tailMax){
      xs.head
    }
    else  tailMax;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because I did not quit the Scala console (in IntelliJ) from sbt with the command:

```
scala> :q
```

and then restarted the the console from sbt, so that everything could be compiled again.

```
> console
```

It`s not necessary to restart sbt, though.

Comment: If someone is using IntelliJ, just press `Ctrl+F5` to restart the console.

Comment: @InfZero - alternatively ALT + F12 to open the Terminal in IntelliJ where the sbt - file is located, type sbt to start the scala built tool and then type "run" to execute the main object or type "console" afterwards and import/type the objects/methods that should be tested/executed.

Answer (score 1):

I have suffered the same problem. But I have fixed it.

The solution is that you should restart your "sbt console", and import the module again, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code as follows (I'm using sbt-1.3.13) :
package example

```
object Lists {

  def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) 0
    else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)
  }

  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    val head = xs.head
    val tail = xs.tail
    if (tail.isEmpty) head
    else {
      val m = max(tail)
      if (head >= m) head else m
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't max also be written like this:   `def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException()
    else xs.sorted.reverse.head
  }`